# Why is the Related Entries code showing after upgrading to EE 2.6.1?

Tags: related-entries

I updated a client site today from 2.5.5 to 2.6.1 which automatically converted the related entries tag on the site.

However, I now have a new problem. For some reason the code is displaying on the [page](http://corecubed.com/blog):

> Author {related_entries id="blog_author"} The Great Keyword Hunt: How
>   to Know What SEO Keywords Your Business Should Target
>   {/related_entries}

Here is the code:

```
<span>{blog_author}
                        {if status == "open"}<a href="{blog_author:title_permalink=/about/bio}">{blog_author:title}</a><br />{blog_author:staff_title}{/if}
                        {if status == "closed"}<a href="{path=/about}">{blog_author:title}</a><br />{blog_author:staff_title}{/if}{/blog_author}</span>
```

Any clues why the code is showing like that?

Comment: Are you using file-based templates? If so, verify that the files have the code updated.

Comment: Hi Derek. Yes, I am and that appears to be the problem. Thanks. Please elevate your comment to an reply and I'll give you credit for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using file-based templates, and during the upgrade only the database version of your templates were upgraded to use the new syntax (possibly due to insufficient permissions on the updater's part).